# Passing WPARAM into DragQueryFile not compatible?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm kinda confused. When a file is dragged onto a window with WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES flagged it places a PostMessage into the WndProc function, which sets UINT message to WM_DROPFILES and, according to

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774303(v=vs.85).aspx

the WPARAM = (WPARAM) (HDROP) hDrop; So am I wrong to assume that I can use the WPARAM to initialize the HDROP or just pass it into the DragQueryFile ??

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
switch (message) {
case WM_CREATE:
    return 0;

case WM_DROPFILES:
    TCHAR* FilePath;
    HDROP hDrop = wParam; //wParam cannot be used to ini. an entity of type HDROP
    //HDROP hdrop = (HDROP)wParam; initialization of hDrop is skipped by case label
    DragQueryFile(wParam, 0, FilePath, 0); //wParam not compatible
    return 0;

case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return 0;
}
return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Every kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Why `c++` tag here? This is pure C.

Comment: @i486: If it's being passed through a C++ compiler, it is C++. I'm not even convinced C would give that error.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition C++ compilers work as C compilers for `.c` source files or have option for this. Win32 API is in C and in the example above there is nothing C++.

Comment: @i486: GCC if running in C mode is a C compiler, not a C++ compiler. You simply cannot tell from the small snippet of code above whether the OP is writing C or C++, period. The fact that they chose the [tag:c++] tag is firm evidence that it is C++, way more so than your "this is pure C" assertion unsupported by any evidence of any kind.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition The sample in the question is in C, Win32 API is based on C, not C++. At least everything in the possible ansfer of the question will be in C. Then - why talking about C++?

Comment: @i486: It's like you're not listening at all. And I'm sure it's deliberately ironic that the currently highest scored answer involves namespcaes and C++11 features, neither of which are valid in C. Try to engage your brain before writing a comment.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition "currently highest scored answer" with score "1" and total of 2 answers... You have "ultimate" argument. Maybe it is good to engage your brain before your next comment. PS: It is interesting why YOUR answer does not use namespaces and C++ features?

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast wparam to HDROP and then iterate over dropped file paths supplying buffer.

```
case WM_DROPFILES:
{
    auto const drop_handle{reinterpret_cast< ::HDROP >(wParam)};
    auto const dropped_files_count
    {
        ::DragQueryFileW(drop_handle, 0xFFFFFFFF, nullptr, 0)
    };
    ::std::vector< wchar_t > buffer;
    for(::UINT dropped_file_index{0}; dropped_files_count != dropped_file_index; ++dropped_file_index)
    {
        auto const file_path_symbols_count_excluding_terminating_null
        {
            ::DragQueryFileW(drop_handle, dropped_file_index, nullptr, 0)
        };
        if(0 < file_path_symbols_count_excluding_terminating_null)
        {
            auto const buffer_size{file_path_symbols_count_excluding_terminating_null + 1};
            buffer.resize(buffer_size);
            auto const copied_symbols_count_excluding_terminating_null
            {
                ::DragQueryFileW(drop_handle, dropped_file_index, buffer.data(), buffer_size)
            };
            if(copied_symbols_count_excluding_terminating_null == file_path_symbols_count_excluding_terminating_null)
            {
                buffer.back() = L'\0'; // just in case....
                // buffer now contains file path...
            }
        }
    }
    break;
}
```

However note that even though handling `WM_DROPFILES` should work, the preferred way to handle drag-and drop is to implement [`IDropTarget` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679679(v=vs.85).aspx) and [register it as drop target handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678405(v=vs.85).aspx) for your application.

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there. You had the right answer, but you commented it out, due to a different error relating to your use of `case` labels. Instead of going backwards with your `HDROP` and `WPARAM`, you should just have fixed that different error ;)

The cast is correct, but you need to scope your case "body" (because, in fact, a case has no body, or scope of its own), and that's what the error's telling you:

```
case WM_DROPFILES: {
    TCHAR FilePath[MAX_PATH];
    HDROP hdrop = (HDROP)wParam; 
    DragQueryFile(hdrop, 0, FilePath, 0);
    return 0;
 }
```

Here I've added `{` and `}` to introduce a block scope.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `hdrop` as the argument to `DragQueryFile`? The arguments for `lpszFile` and `cch` are also incorrect. You are supposed to either pass a preallocated buffer and its size or pass `NULL` for `lpszFile` to get required buffer size.

Comment: but `TCHAR` doesn't make sense since windows 2000.

Answer (score 0):

add VTT answered.

you can replace `::std::vector< wchar_t > buffer;` with `std::wstring buffer`

code

```
case WM_DROPFILES:
{
    auto const drop_handle{ reinterpret_cast<::HDROP>(wParam) };
    auto const dropped_files_count
    {
        ::DragQueryFileW(drop_handle, 0xFFFFFFFF, nullptr, 0)
    };
    ::std::wstring buffer;
    for (::UINT dropped_file_index{ 0 }; dropped_files_count != dropped_file_index; ++dropped_file_index)
    {
        auto const file_path_symbols_count_excluding_terminating_null
        {
            ::DragQueryFileW(drop_handle, dropped_file_index, nullptr, 0)
        };
        if (0 < file_path_symbols_count_excluding_terminating_null)
        {
            auto const buffer_size{ file_path_symbols_count_excluding_terminating_null + 1 };
            buffer.resize(buffer_size);
            auto const copied_symbols_count_excluding_terminating_null
            {
                ::DragQueryFileW(drop_handle, dropped_file_index, &buffer[0], buffer_size)
            };
            if (copied_symbols_count_excluding_terminating_null == file_path_symbols_count_excluding_terminating_null)
            {
                buffer.back() = L'\0'; // just in case....
                // buffer now contains file path...
                MessageBox(0, buffer.c_str(), buffer.c_str(), MB_OK);
            }
        }
    }
    break;
}
```