# How do i extract dragged & dropped filenames from a DROPFILES struct

Tags: c++, winapi, drag-and-drop

I have a window with no controls with WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES enabled and the event triggers successfully when dragging files from explorer. What I need to do is extract the files to a vector. From what I've read, the wParam is supposed to contain the location of the files within a DROPFILES struct but I don't know how to access them.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK StaticWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR 
uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    if (uMsg == WM_DROPFILES)
    {
       // extract files here
       vector<string> files;

    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I don't need to send them to any controls since my window is for an openGL application, I just need to retain them in a list, how can it be done?

Comment: There are many examples of this on the web. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43823970/485343) one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [`WM_DROPFILES` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/wm-dropfiles):

> Parameters
>
> *hDrop*
>
> A handle to an internal structure describing the dropped files. **Pass this handle to [`DragFinish`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Shellapi/nf-shellapi-dragfinish), [`DragQueryFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Shellapi/nf-shellapi-dragqueryfilea), or [`DragQueryPoint()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Shellapi/nf-shellapi-dragquerypoint) to retrieve information about the dropped files.**
>
> *lParam*
>
> Must be zero.

Simply type-cast the `wParam` to `HDROP` and call the drag-drop functions as needed, eg:

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK StaticWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    if (uMsg == WM_DROPFILES)
    {
       HDROP hDrop = reinterpret_cast<HDROP>(wParam);

       // extract files here
       vector<string> files;
       char filename[MAX_PATH];

       UINT count = DragQueryFileA(hDrop, -1, NULL, 0);
       for(UINT i = 0; i < count; ++i)
       {
          if (DragQueryFileA(hDrop, i, filename, MAX_PATH))
              files.push_back(filename);
       }

       DragFinish(hDrop);
       return 0;
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK StaticWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    if (uMsg == WM_DROPFILES)
    {
       HDROP hDrop = reinterpret_cast<HDROP>(wParam);

       // extract files here
       vector<string> files;
       string filename;

       UINT count = DragQueryFileA(hDrop, -1, NULL, 0);
       for(UINT i = 0; i < count; ++i)
       {
          UINT size = DragQueryFileA(hDrop, i, NULL, 0);
          if (size > 0)
          {
              filename.resize(size);
              DragQueryFileA(hDrop, i, &filename[0], size+1);
              files.push_back(filename);
          }
       }

       DragFinish(hDrop);
       return 0;
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```